# Accessing data in localStorage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have been writing a Chrome extension, and I noticed that I can access it very simply with code like

```
var x = localStorage.x;
```

or

```
var y = "value";
localStorage.y = y;
```

However, I don't think that I've ever seen this method documented. Usually, I've seen something like

```
var x = localStorage.getItem(x);
var y = "value";
localstorage.setItem(y, "value");
```

Are there problems with using my original technique? Should I switch?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's `localStorage` object appears to implement the [HTML5 `Storage` interface](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0), which mentions that storage elements can be manipulated by directly accessing the relevant properties.

The [relevant documentation from Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) advises use of the `setItem` and `getItem` methods, though it doesn't clarify why.

```
Note: Although the values can be set and read via the standard JavaScript property access method usage of getItem and setItem methods is recommended.
```

In practice, I believe it should not matter which method of assignment you use.  If the interface is implemented properly, direct property assignment should, effectively, call `setItem` and `getItem`.